# QUERY with double condition in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a table similar to this

```
A     B     C     D     E
a1    b1    5     d1   
a2    b2    5     d2
a3    b1    3           e1
a4    b3    4           e2
a5    b1    5     d3    e3
```

I'm trying to figure out a query that shows A,B,C,D if the value in D is not empty

```
SELECT A,B,C,D WHERE D is not null
```

Also, if the value in the C column is lower or equal to 3 I need it to show the values in column E, even if D is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(A2:E, "where D is not null or C <= 3", 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! That was pretty simple! Thank you very much!